# Button image breaks on form submit

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the src of an image within a button element when the form is submitted. For some reason the new image src fails to load (broken link image in chrome, nothing in FF) when the form submits, however if I use `return false;` I can see the image swapping over correctly. Have tried using background images and this seems to work, but it messes with the default user-agent button styles.

Here is the code I am using and a sample fiddle (change `return true;` to `return false;` to see the image working).

```
<form method="post" id="testForm" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="someField" /> 
    <button type="submit">Submit <img src="" /></button>    
</form>
```

.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $( "#testForm" ).submit( function () {
        var submitBtn = $( "#testForm" ).find( "button" );
        submitBtn.attr( "disabled", true ).find( "img" )[0].src = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/car.png";
        return true;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LV326/15/

Any ideas why the form being submitted would affect the image? I'm sure its something simple but its had me stumped for quite some time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do realize that submitting a form requires the page to reload, so swapping the image makes no difference once the page loads again?

Comment: @adeneo Not necessarily. What if the form has its `target` attribute set to another window/iframe?

Comment: @rvighne - I don't see a target attribute ?

Comment: @adeneo Neither do I, but this is a temporary sort of thing (notice how the `action` is set to `#`) so they may have removed it. After all, you can't reference other windows from a jsFiddle.

Comment: @rvighne - But you surely could make a form open a new window in jSFiddle, and it seems strange not to mention that the form submits to a new tab.

Comment: It would of course be great if **@jade** could follow up and tell us what the heck is going on here.

Comment: @adeneo That I must agree on. He/she just set the question and left -- no comments, no accepts, nothing.

Comment: @adeneo @ rvighne Sorry for the delay in responding (did not expect to get so many answers/comments in such a short space of time!). I am aware that submitting a form requires the page to reload, in my case it runs a report which can take several minutes, so the user is stuck on this same page until the server responds,.I wan't to make sure they know the report is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form's submitting takes priority over the image loading, so it never loads. You must load the image, then submit the form manually:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var submitted = false;
    $( "#testForm" ).submit( function (e) {
        if (submitted) return;
        e.preventDefault();

        var submitBtn = $( "#testForm" ).find( "button" );
        var img = submitBtn.attr( "disabled", true ).find( "img" )[0];

        img.onload = function() {
            $("#testForm").submit();
        };

        submitted = true;
        img.src = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/car.png";
    });
});
```

However, the form submitting will (usually) cause the page to redirect. If you don't want this to happen, then consider a XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Thanks @rvighne, its hard to choose which answer to accept, but this one explained most concisely that the loading of the image is halted/interrupted by the form submission.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that the browser doesn't display the image. In fact, once the image has been cached, you can see it just before submitting the form.

The problem is that, normally, the form is submitted (and a new page loaded) before downloading the image.

If you want to make sure it will be displayed, you can use `preventDefault` to avoid submitting the form, and add a `load` event handler to the image which submits the form:

```
$( "#testForm" ).submit( function (e) {
    var that = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    $( "#testForm" ).find( "button" )
        .attr( "disabled", true )
        .find( "img" )
            .on('load', function(){ that.submit(); })
            .attr('src', "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/car.png");
});
```

You could also consider using a timeout to be sure that the image is shown during some time:

```
.on('load', function(){ setTimeout(that.submit, 1000); })
```

Comment: This will just get into an endless loop. Also, the `setTimeout` serves no purpose.

Comment: @rvighne This isn't an endless loop, because (in vanilla-js, unlike jQuery) `.submit()` doesn't fire any `submit` event! And `setTimeout` delays submitting the form so that the image can be seen during more time.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't know if that's true, but now I see you're not triggering jQuery's submit().

Answer (score 0):

Realising that the form submission was interrupting the loading of the image, I ended up preloading  the icon using something like `$('<img/>')[0].src = 'https://icon.png';` in the page load event. This seems to display the image reliably now (although the animated gif im using doesn't seem to loop in FF, but that might be a separate issue).

Answer (score -1):

You need to stop the form submitting before you change the image, and then submit it once that is done swapping. Why? The form submit continues during the image replacement, so you need to make it stop until ready.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $( "#testForm" ).submit( function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // stops form submission long enough to swap
        var submitBtn = $( "#testForm" ).find( "button" );
        submitBtn.attr( "disabled", true ).find( "img" )[0].src = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/car.png";
        $("#testForm").submit(); // submits it when ready
    });
 });
```

The preferred way to handle this is to change the submit to a regular button and use a click event, like this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $( "#testFormButton" ).click( function (e) {
        $( "#testFormButton" ).attr( "disabled", true ).find( "img" )[0].src = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/car.png";
        $("#testForm").submit(); // submits it when ready
    });
 });
```

This way you don't have the form misbehaving when you don't want it to. You control when it submits. Works exactly the same way but you can do all the things you need to first.

Comment: The `return` statement will just stop the function there.

Comment: won't a `return false;`  not work? You'll never get beyond the return statement.

Comment: your submit() at the end will still run the handler you defined that will hit `e.preventDefault()` again and again. Infinite recursion detected.

Comment: The better way to do this is to not use submit buttons, but have a plain button and change this to a click() event, so you can do what you need to and control the submit at the end, when you are ready.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to intercept the submit, and then submit the form again after you do the swap.

```
$(function () {
    var submitted = false;
    $( "#testForm" ).submit(function (e) {
        var frm = this;
        if (!submitted) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var submitBtn = $( "#testForm" ).find( "button" );
            var img = submitBtn.attr( "disabled", true ).find( "img" );
            img[0].src = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/car.png";
            submitted = true;
            img.load(function() {
                $(frm).submit();
            });
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Good try, but this still won't work because image loading is asynchronous: the form will submit before the image starts loading.

Comment: @rvighne - And yours won't work because triggering the forms jQuery submit handler still prevents the default action.

Comment: @adeneo Ouch. Good catch! But my argument still holds.

Comment: As a sidenote, doing `this.submit()` triggers the native handler and avoids the preventDefault issue.

Comment: I've updated my answer to actually work correctly and wait for the image to load.